# How to simplify an expression containing cubic and square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a>0, \ b>0, \ c>0$ and $$U=\frac{\sqrt[3]{ab\sqrt{c}}-a\sqrt[4]{b^2c}}{\sqrt[6]{a^3b^2c}},$$

then $U$ is equal to:

a) $\sqrt[6]{\frac{1-a^4b\sqrt{c}}{a}}$

b) $\frac{1-\sqrt[3]{a^2\sqrt[4]{b^2c}}}{\sqrt[6]{a}}$

c) $\frac{\sqrt[6]{a}}{\sqrt[6]{1+a^4b\sqrt{c}}}$

d) None of the above.

Setting $a=b=c=1$ just excludes option c). Other than this I have no idea how to proceed. I want to try substituting in $a=b=c=2$ but it becomes too complicated. Any suggestions on how to eliminate mor options?

Comment: Try making the variable substitutions $a = x^{12}$, $b=y^{12}$, $c=z^{12}$. This will make the expressions nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the variable substitutions $a = x^{12}$, $b = y^{12}$, $c = z^{12}$ that I suggested in the comments, this expression becomes $$\frac{x^4 y^4 z^2 - x^{12} y^6 z^3}{x^6 y^4 z^2} = \frac{1 - x^8 y^2 z}{x^2} = \frac{1 - a^{2/3} b^{1/6} c^{1/12}}{a^{1/6}}$$
which equals (b).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: try to replace roots with fractional powers. i.e, $\sqrt{a}=a^{\frac{1}{2}}$. You will find that (b) is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Factor out by $$(ab\sqrt {c})^\frac {1}{3} $$ and simplify.
you will find the expression $(b) $.
You can also check it by taking $$a=b=c=10^{12} $$